# Direct sum of vector spaces and quotients

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, and $W_{1}, W_{2}$ are subspaces of $V$. Assume $V=W_{1}\oplus W_{2}$. Does it necessarily follow that $V/W_{1}$ is isomorphic to $W_{2}$ (as vector spaces)?

I feel like this is a well-known fact, but I have seen enough counterexamples for similar statements that I am not so sure.

Comment: *Hint:* $\dim V = \dim W_1 + \dim W_2$.

Comment: If you have a direct sum decomposition, you don't need finite-dimensionality. Consider the restriction of the quotient map to $W_2$.

Comment: @njguliyev, Daniel, thanks very much for the hints :) Makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See $\mathrm V$ has an abelian group. $\mathrm W_1$ is a sub-group of $\mathrm V$ and you want to make the quotient. This is always possible, but here you are in the best possible case, $\mathrm W_1$ is a direct factor !
You also have the split exact sequence
 $$ 0 \to \mathrm W_1 \to \mathrm W_1 \oplus \mathrm W_2 \to \mathrm W_2 \to 0.$$